# egrep issue- need to search different patterns?

Tags: unix

Need a grep one liner [ without pipe ] which would check multiple expressions in a single command

cat FILE | egrep OH|OI is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is a simple:

```
egrep 'OH|OI' FILE
```

The command you have (without the quotes):

```
cat FILE | egrep OH|OI
```

will attempt to `cat` the file through `egrep` looking for `OH` then *pipe the results of that* through an executable `OI` (which probably doesn't exist).

The quotes will fix that for you so that `OH|HI` is a single argument to the `egrep` rather than something the shell processes.

Answer (score 0):

Just try:
`cat FILE | egrep 'OH|OI'`

Answer (score 0):

Eliminate the pipe by supplying the filename.

```
egrep 'OH|OI' filename
```